# Can I cancel my plane tickets to Russia after obtaining a Russian visa?

Tags: visas, trains, russia, dutch-citizens, trans-siberian

I want to get a Russian tourist visa to take the Trans Mongolian express from Beijing. However I will not book my train tickets in advance.

Can I book flights to get my visa, cancelling them afterwards to enter/exit Russia by train?

Comment: I would enquire if you need any tickets at all to get a visa. Since any request for a visa could be rejected, it would be bad to require people to buy tickets ahead which might be either more expensive, or not refundable.

Answer (score 5):

[You do not need the **tickets**](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Russia/Netherlands/Tourist.html) to obtain your visa, you only need a confirmation that you'll be hosted as a tourist. This usually is a [hotel booking voucher](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/1432/19) or some similar document, you should contact your consulate for more detailed information.

All in all, hotel booking can be easily canceled, usually without any cost, if you do it in advance.